# Invalid CurrentPageIndex value. It must be >= 0 and < the PageCount

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

i want to bind my data Gridview  but it throw an error.
 i allow paging when i click on new page e.g 1.2.3 then the above error throw
here is my code. 
the one is page index change and the other one is my method of BindGrid.
the error come when i click one new page 2 or 3 etc

updated code

```
 protected void DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged(Object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = Session["data"] as DataTable;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable data = storedProcedureManager.sp_inactiveFiles(
                providerID,
                 days, CaseTypeID, CollectorID, user.UserRegID);
        lblMsg.Text = data.Rows.Count + " Record's Found.";
        log.Info(lblMsg.Text);
        Session["data"] = data;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = data;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();

        log.Info("Report Displayed.");

    }
```

Comment: what is e.NewPageIndex value?is it less than page count?

Comment: this was added on another post of same error so i also put it here , but fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem what is happening is when you fetch the data again in BindGrid() method you must be getting less number of pages.so you can do two things.

1)If you are filtering your data then reset the page index to 1.

```
protected void DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged(Object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        BindGrid();
    }
private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable data = storedProcedureManager.sp_inactiveFiles(
                providerID,
                 days,CaseTypeID,CollectorID,user.UserRegID);
        lblMsg.Text = data.Rows.Count + " Record's Found.";
        log.Info(lblMsg.Text);

        DataGrid1.DataSource = data;
        DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();

        log.Info("Report Displayed.");

    }
```

2)If you are not filtering your data then store the datagrid value in a session object and use this for pageing.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    BindGrid();
    }

  }
protected void DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged(Object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = Session["value"] as DataTable;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable data = storedProcedureManager.sp_inactiveFiles(
                providerID,
                 days,CaseTypeID,CollectorID,user.UserRegID);
        lblMsg.Text = data.Rows.Count + " Record's Found.";
        log.Info(lblMsg.Text);
        Session["value"]=data;
        DataGrid1.DataSource = data;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();

        log.Info("Report Displayed.");

    }
```

Comment: Session["value"] is session object for holding your data.this object you can use through out your session.for understanding session check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1287741.aspx?How+do+I+declare+a+session+variable+)

Comment: DataGrid1_PageIndexChanged **will be** a **postback**.if you write your code inside (!IsPostBack), your code is useless.

Comment: I think my second solution is useful for you.check the second solution

Comment: the value in session u mean all columns of data gridview ? ?

Comment: yes. your whole of the data table is saved in session

Comment: i tried second solution but when i click on next page it didn't show next records. the next page is empty page display no records

Comment: could you pls edit your question and paste the modified code?

Comment: what do you mean by 'the next page is empty page display no records'?is it throwing any error?

Comment: no it does not show any record when i click on next page e.g 1.2.3.4 etc

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            
            BindGrid();
        }

Comment: Same code is working for me.I am not understanding why it is not working for you.Do u have any other code related to this datagrid?

Comment: i think if i use Gridview control instead datagrid control it will work ? ?

Comment: Sure it will work.just replace DataGrid1 with gridview ID

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGrid1.DataSource = data;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
```

Reset the `CurrentPageIndex` to 0 after the page has been bound.